# Magento 1: Problems translating "This is a required field."

Tags: magento-1.9

For my configurable products I'm trying to translate the sentence "This is a required field.". But I cant seem to translate it for some reason.

**I've tried editting the following files:**

prototype/validation.js,

local/language files,

\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Helper\Js.php

**I've also tried adding translations with jQuery with the following code:**

```
selector.attr('This is a required field.', Translator.translate('Dit veld is verplicht.'))
```

**Code for calling the product options**

```
  <div class="custom-options">
    <?php if (!$sname) :?>
      <?php if ($_item->isSuper() || $_item->getHasOptions()) : ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChild('groupedoptions')->setProduct($_item)->toHtml(); ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
      <?php if ($_item->isSuper() || $_item->getHasOptions()) : ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChild('groupedoptions')->setProduct($_item)->toHtml(); ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif;//micosolutions ?>
  </div>
```

I've tried replacing

```
echo $this->getChild('groupedoptions')
```

with

```
echo $this->getChild__('groupedoptions')
```

Comment: You can add it to your Translate CSV file

Comment: I've already tried that, but no results :(

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on the language but -

The way I would go about this is as follows.

Make sure that the translation has a " __ " - thats two underscores - before the code.

Example::

```
< label for="billing-address-select">< ?php echo $this->__('Select a billing address from your address book or enter a new address.') ?>
```

Notice the "$this->__('Select..." - that tells magento to translate.

After this is checked go to app/etc/[desired translation language]/ - find the file you are wanting to update (I think its Mage_Catalog.csv) and make the translation and save.

That is how I went about making a translation for one of my clients and it worked well.

Something to keep in mind  - When I had the task of translating, the code I was making an edit to had a href in the middle (think of a click here type thing). I had to translate the text before and after the button. The translation didnt work with the href being in the middle because the computer was looking for "something link this" and it only saw "something" [link] "this".

If you have the raw code - please post it and I can see if I can further help out.

Comment: I've editted the post with the code

Comment: I see whats going on - I believe that the variable "groupedoptions" is not being read by the translation. Change that variable to html. In my understanding - the way that the translation action works in magento is that it reads html text and looks for the exact translation in CSV and changes the output.